# Java volume doesn't change in Eclipse under Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, audio

I have a little problem:
I'm using javazoom.* to make a simple music player. To change volume level i use

```
private BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
player.setGain(<double value between 0..1>);
```

Method *.setGain() works directly with FloatControl from java.sound.*
When I star Java application in eclipse(under Linux) music don't change it level. But when I export Java application to app.jar everything works fine(under all OS). Also all everything works in eclipse that working under Windows. Can some one explain why it happens?

Tested software:

- OS: WinXP, Win7; Ubuntu 12.04, 13.10(Some 32-bit, Some 64)
- JVM: OpenJDK 6,7; SunJDK 6
- Eclipse Kepler(4,*) and Indigo(3,7).
- Javazoom latest

**Solved**

This happens only when you start project under eclipse.
If you makes *.jar and starts in OS volume change works without any problems.

Comment: **Solved**

This happens only when you start project under eclipse. If you makes *.jar and starts in OS volume change works without any problems.

Comment: Doesn't sound solved at all; sounds like you found a workaround. As long as you don't understand what was wrong, you haven't really solved anything.

Comment: This is problem of eclipse JavaVM start options and|or JavaVM to pulse audio  connection.

Comment: Please don't edit question titles to include "solved". Simply accept an answer.

Comment: Sorry. It is old habit from Ubuntu forums.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solved**

This happens only when you start project under eclipse. If you makes *.jar and starts in OS volume change works without any problems.